# How to press exclamation mark key in Emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs, ide, elisp, archlinux

I begin to work with Emacs and decide to learn all its shortcuts. To execute a shell command there is a `M-!` shortcut. But I don't know how to press exclamation mark key. Usually I press `Shift-1` but when in Emacs I do `Alt-Shift-1` nothing happened. I tried `Alt-1` but it is `M-1`. I know it is a noob question but can someone please help me?

Comment: Test f1 k alt-shift-1.

Comment: Or `Esc` key then `!` key

Comment: Normally, `Alt+Shift+1` would work. Are you in a terminal and / or using SSH and / or a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`? (Basile's suggestion of `Esc` followed by `Shift+1` should work in any case. Note that you do *not* hold `Esc`; press it then release it.)

Comment: @Chris I use GUI Emacs

Comment: @Chris when I pfress f1 k shift-1 it shows it is an exclamation mark. But when I press it as shortcut it interprets it as M-1

Comment: @HarryDeveloper1212, try your other Alt key.

Comment: @Chris THanks for help it was a keyboard layout issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed! The problem was with keyboard layout for language switching. In my KDE environment there was an `Alt-Shift` key for switching languages.

So if someone will encounter with this issue - please check your keyobard layout shortcuts: probably you have an `Alt (meta) -Shift` key for this. If so - change it to another.